# Set a post to draft once depending on a post meta value (passed certain date)?

Tags: wp-update-post

To give better context I have a CPT on my site called "Upcoming Games". I have the posts ordered by the datepicker:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'upcoming-games',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'       => 'release_date',
        'meta_value'     => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
        'meta_compare'   => '>=',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => is_front_page() ? 3 : 12,
);
```

But I want to take it a step further, if a game is released on August 1, 2016 and the current date is August 2, 2016, technically it's no longer an "Upcoming Game" so I'd like the post to be drafted without manually having to go into WP each time and change it myself.

Comment: You could schedule something with WP_Cron that loops through all published posts of the `upcoming-games` type, compares the current time to the ACF field for the post (using `get_field()` if I recall correctly) and use `wp_update_post()` to change the `post_status`

Comment: @kaiser You marked it as a duplicate, but I want to achieve the opposite.

Comment: Clarified your question. Keep in mind that 3rd party software is out of scope and we can keep this question only open as long as you can solve your problem with WP only.

Comment: What 3rd Party Software was mentioned in here? The ACF plugin?